Add and show errors saving a post Wordpress
For my CPT I use some extra meta data.
I want verify the meta data and if there is something wrong show an error.
With some research I try this code
add_action('save_post', function($post_id){
    if(isset($_POST['joLink'])){
        if($_POST['joLink'] !== ''){
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'joLink', $_POST['joLink']);
        }else{
            add_settings_error(
                'missing-link',         
                'missing-link',         
                'Link may not empty!',          
                'error' 
            );
            add_action('admin_notices', function(){
                $message = '<div id="message" class="error"><p><ul>';         
                foreach ( $errors as $error ) {         
                    $message .= '<li>' . $error['message'] . '</li>';         
                }         
                $message .= '</ul></p></div>';      
                echo $message;
            });
        }
    }else{
        delete_post_meta($post_id, 'joLink');
    }
    
    return $post_id;
});

If I save the post with a empty link Wordpress saved the data and returns success.
What I am missing?

One way to cancel the post save is just die.

add_action('save_post', function ($post_id) {
    if (true) {
        wp_die(__('Link may not empty!', 'your-text-domain'));
    }
    return $post_id;
});



This works only in the old editor. I use the rest editor. I think this works with AJAX?

i am not sure what is that editor. how are you saving the post?

I save the post with the code in my question. In the register from the CPT I set show_in_rest'  => true Wordpress use another editor/screen. By saving the post Wordpress send the data with AJAX I think and does not refresh the page. the wp_die function does not work but gives a 500 error in the console

maybe you can use wp_send_json_error instead, if you are detecting ajax

The Gutenberg block editor use Javascript to display messages
 wp.data.dispatch( 'core/notices' ).createNotice(
        'error',
        'Hey, something going wrong!',
        { 
            id:'greetings-notice', 
            isDismissible: true,
        }
    );

